# kartograph.js - very simple map

Tags: jquery, kartograph

As a beginner i want to get the most basic example to work.
So i downloaded a map from [here](http://datamaps.cc/admin1/EU/DEU.svg)
Looked into the file to find that the id for the first and only `'g'` is `'admin1'`.

So, i started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="map.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="k.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $script(['/js/jquery.min.js'], 'jquery');
        $script(['/js/raphael-min.js', '/js/kartograph.js', '/js/chroma.min.js'], 'kartograph');
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $script.ready(['jquery','kartograph'], function() {
            $(function() {
                map = $K.map('#map');
                map.loadMap('DEU.svg', function(map) {
                    map.addLayer({ id: "admin1" });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>        
</body>
</html>
```

That is it basically - it is not showing anything. I checked the file locations, and checked if everything after the `$script.ready` function was running. all ok - but no result.
I took all the files I include from the kartograph lib folder (on git) - and added the `k.css` and a small `map.css`

`map.css` looks like this:

```
#map {
width: 900px;
height: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me which tool created this SVG? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my resurrecting this after 2 years has caused the OP dismay, my sincerest apologies. I intend only to help others who may have been as dumbfounded as I was at this problem.

The following `loadMap()` function works for me:

```
map.loadMap('DEU.svg', function () {
    map.addLayer("admin1");
});
```

So it seems you don't need to say `map.addLayer({ id: "admin1" })`. You can add styles or event handlers after the layer name, like so

```
map.loadMap('DEU.svg', function () {
    map.addLayer("admin1", {
        styles: {
            stroke: '#aaa',
            fill: '#f6f4f2'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Google Chrome will not load your SVG. Firefox works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to reproduce your problem, I found out that [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) might not been loaded. If you copied the files from [kartograph.org](http://www.kartograph.org/), try changing `/js/raphael-min.js` to [`/js/raphael.min.js`](http://www.kartograph.org/js/raphael.min.js).

Comment: @ThomasDeutsch Oh, I overlooked that. But I found a possible typo. Please see the edited answer.